# Does PyroCMS have a Search function?

Tags: search, pyrocms

I'm trying to search my pages and posts - is this a native concept with PyroCMS?

Comment: Here is the new link to the docs for the Search feature: https://pyrocms.com/help/developer-tools/search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyroCMS v2.2.0 comes with Search built in for Pages and Blog articles and has hooks for module developers to enable search for their content too. Sadly 2.2.0 is not officially released, but it is very close to a beta release no; maybe you could give it a try?

https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/tree/2.2/develop

You can then search using the search plugin, or by going to the /search page.

Comment: What sort of known bugs are there?

Comment: If the bugs were known they'd have been fixed. Give it a go, but back your stuff up (like you should with any upgrade). If you spot anything then post an issue: https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/issues

Comment: Here is the documentation for Search http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/search . 2.2/develop has reached beta1 and is moving on to beta2 so its getting increasingly stable.